# The action 'facebook' could not be found for AuthenticationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am trying to configure FB connect with my app. It used to work fine until July 18, 2012. I have not modified any code, but now it stopped working.

Using devise and omniauth

When I am trying to connect with FB I get this error:

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'facebook' could not be found for AuthenticationsController):

config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:6:in `call_with_quiet_assets'

GET /users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQD...#*=*

There is only create method in AuthenticationsController, no facebook nor twitter, twitter is working though.

app_id and app-secret match

Everything works fine with Twitter, both FB and Twitter were setup at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :passwords => "passwords", :omniauth_callbacks => "authentications"} is routing to facebook method not create

Comment: request.env["action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie"]["omniauth.params"]["invite_type"] == 'facebook' this line returns no method error